# Styling a CSS font face to have two custom fonts on a html page

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

I have a web page that successfully uses one of the two font-faces I have here. I want the user to be able to see a top menu div tag that is styled with the Cubano font while the rest of the text of the page will be open sans. @font-face seems to be just unique so I cant add two font-familys to it.

EDIT: Demo can be seen here on the [rate1.html](http://www.jakegosskuehn.com/rate1.html) page.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSans';
src: url("fonts/opensans.ttf") format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Cubano';
src: url("fonts/cubano-webfont.ttf") format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal
}


body {
font: 32px/40px 'OpenSans', sans-serif;
color: #777;
}

body div.recent {
font: 32px/40px 'Cubano', sans-serif;
color: #777999;
}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me....can you demo this **not** working?

Comment: which one isn't working?

Comment: I do notice the fonts aren't in the same folder...

Comment: Added demo in post. The 'recent' projects are what I'm trying to cubano at the top..

Comment: `@font-face seems to be just unique so I cant add two font-familys to it` this is not true.

Comment: Fonts are not loading in your page, I guess your path is incorrect and both fonts are not loading (not opensans nor cubano fonts are loaded)

Comment: The `cubano` font is NOT in the font folder...start there.

Comment: I made a error in posting this. I added src: before the url and its able to get Cubano. Its not able to pick up opensans.

Comment: Also not sure if I put up the right link, but the demo is actually up.

Comment: It looks like the demo CSS and the code you gave us are different. Did you forget to save something?

Answer (score 1):

For the Open Sans you can use @import (in .css file):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

or link it in the `<head>` :

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

See more options [here](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)